# How to take certain characters from the middle of the cell and place them at the end

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am in the process of cleaning up some data. Someone else put the size of products in the middle of the cell when it should be at the end. These sizes range from XXS-XXL. There are some other sizes such as 1inX6ft. These obviously have more variations though (like certain inches by certain inches or certain inches by certain feet) so while a formula to extract all size types and put them at the end of the end would be ideal, I need to at least get a formula for the XXS-XXL possible sizes (assuming I could use something like {XS, SM, M, L, XL, XXL} in the formula given if the former isn't possible.

Here are some examples of what I have:

```
RC D CLP CLR SM PNK TRTN
RC D CIRQUE S HRN XXS CORAL
RC D LEASH 3/4inX6ft FOX
RC D CLP CLR LG BEAR CAMP
RC D BARK NOTES 3/4in FRIENDLY
```

Here are some examples of what I need:

```
RC D CLP CLR PNK TRTN SM
RC D CIRQUE S HRN CORAL XXS
RC D LEASH FOX 3/4inX6ft
RC D CLP CLR BEAR CAMP LG
RC D BARK NOTES FRIENDLY 3/4in
```

I've only been cutting and pasting so far. I thought about recording macros for the different sizes XS-XXL but don't think that would be quicker since I control + v paste the sizes at the end after cutting them.

Comment: This will probably work better in vba than a formula.  A formula will be quite long and unruly.

Comment: What are your other rules for identifying a size besides (XS, SM, M, L, XL, XXL)? I see some numbers in the other two examples. Can we assume that a word with numbers is also a size?

Comment: Hey, JNevill. Yeah, any word with numbers is also a size. For example, a leash might be 1inX6ft. I also forgot to add that some go by oz (ounces), g (grams), cu in (cubic inches), lb (pounds), in (inches), Mini, Jumbo, CT (count), some just have a number (like 7 for size 7), L (liter). Unfortunately, some contain both as well. For example, a cell might have 2CT MD or 4CT 4oz. In these cases, the size and weight, especially weight, always go at the end; the CT designations can stay where they are.

Comment: Hey, Scott. That's no problem, I don't have any issues using VBA. I only said formula since that is what I am more used to working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a User Defined Function that iterates the "words" looking for matches and moves them to the back.  It uses `Like` to try an find the other measurements by pattern.

You can add other patterns/words to the `Array` to move them also.

```
Function MoveToBack(str As String) As String
    Dim ExArr() As Variant
    ExArr = Array("XXS", "XS", "SM", "M", "LG", "XL", "XX", "*#in*", "*#ft*")

    Dim strArr() As String
    strArr = Split(str)

    Dim last As String
    last = ""

    Dim temp As String
    temp = ""



    Dim strEach As Variant
    For Each strEach In strArr
        Dim hre As Boolean
        hre = False

        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(ExArr) To UBound(ExArr)
            If strEach Like ExArr(i) Then
                hre = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        If hre Then
            last = strEach
        Else
            temp = temp & strEach & " "
        End If
    Next strEach

    MoveToBack = Application.Trim(temp & last)

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, thanks again for your help, Scott! You're always a lifesaver! I want to double check - if I forgot a size designation, would I simply just add it to the parenthesis in the third line (after ExArr = Array)? If so, is there a limit to how many size designations I can have in total?

Comment: Also, can I add "L" for liter or would that move any word that contains the letter L to the end of the cell?

Comment: You can add what ever you want, not sure on the limit.  But it should be sufficiently large.

Comment: Items without wildcards `*` will look for exact matches

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. Is it necessary to have * before and after a size like "in"? Doesn't the wildcard mean anything connected before and after "in" should be included? Also, I just had two cells where I entered the formula created in VBA and it completely deleted the size part of the cell for some reason. One example is NDC/D/Odor Free Bully 12in Skinny which became NDC/D/Odor Free Bully Skinny with the formula.

Comment: It was picking up the `in` in `Skinny` I have added the fact that a number must precede the `in` with the `#` in the array.  See edit @CTEAGUE212

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. That edit worked, thanks again for all of your help!